# How to draw a vertical line across the whole plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot and I want to draw some vertical lines covering the whole range of the y-axis, without having to worry about the numerical values of that range. [This matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/vline_hline_demo.html) demonstrates the functionality I'm looking for, and it works fine for me, but a very similar code does not. What am I doing wrong?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)
y = np.random.normal(scale=0.01, size=200).cumsum()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
ax[0].plot(y)
ax[0].vlines([25, 50, 100], [0], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3], color='C1')
ax[1].plot(y)
ax[1].vlines([25, 50, 100], [0], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3], color='C1')
ax[1].vlines([0], 0, 1, color='k', linestyle='dashed',
    transform=ax[1].get_xaxis_transform())
```

Expected: both plots have the same y-limits

Actual result: the plot on the right has the wrong limits

[image]

Using matplotlib 3.7.1 on python 3.11.3.

Comment: Not clear what is wrong in the result. Which vlines size are you not happy with? The orange one (but then, why explicitly specifying different sizes?), the dashed one? or all of them?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axhspan_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-axhspan-demo-py

Comment: @PaulH Maybe write up an answer that outlines the three main methods for drawing straight lines in matplotlib, i.e. `axhline`/`axvline`, `axhspan`/`axvspan`, and `hlines`/`vlines`? I was going to do it, but considering you suggested it first, you have "first rights".

Comment: @jared nah. go for it. i'll sit this one out

Comment: `axvline` is a complete solution for the example as given, but unfortunately it only accepts a scalar as `x`.

Comment: `ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()` and `ax.vlines(x=..., ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, ...)`, or use `axvline` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Set ymin and ymax to 0 and 1.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)
y = np.random.normal(scale=0.01, size=200).cumsum()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
ax[0].plot(y)
ax[0].vlines([25, 50, 100], 0, 1, color='C1', 
  transform=ax[0].get_xaxis_transform())
ax[1].plot(y)
ax[1].vlines([25, 50, 100], 0, 1, color='C1', 
  transform=ax[1].get_xaxis_transform())
ax[1].vlines([0], 0, 1, color='k', linestyle='dashed', 
  transform=ax[1].get_xaxis_transform())
```

As for the y-limits you can set them with:

```
ax[0].set_ylim([-0.05, 0.3])
ax[1].set_ylim([-0.05, 0.3])
```

Comment: OK, that makes the axis limits the same on both sides, but that's not really what I wanted. Edited above to clarify.

Comment: See also the linked matplotlib example.

Comment: `ax[0].axvline` is probably the better choice here

Comment: @Ilya I updated the answer hopefully this solves your problem?

Comment: @Paul H that is a good suggestion. Edit on the answer if you want.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that -- like the example in the matplotlib docs -- doesn't use `set_ylim` or any of its friends.